# what is alternative for begin invoke in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
static long dd = 0, hh = 0, mm = 0, ss = 0, ms = 0;

    static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    Timer stopwatch_timer;

    static Boolean Stp = true;

private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Stopwatch start 
    {

        Stp = false;
        stopwatch_timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(updatedisplay), TimerDisplay, 0, 100);
        stopwatch.Start();

    }

    private void updatedisplay(object displayblock)
    {
        ms = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        TextBox Bd = (TextBox)displayblock;
        ss = ms / 1000; ms = ms % 1000;
        mm = ss / 60; ss = ss % 60;
        hh = mm / 60; mm = mm % 60;
        dd = hh / 24; hh = hh % 24;
        Bd.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { Bd.Text = dd.ToString("00") + ":" + hh.ToString("00") + ":" + mm.ToString("00") + ":" + ss.ToString("00") + ":" + ms.ToString("000"); });

    } //Cant use begin Invoke Error - Windows.Ui.Core.Coredispatcher doesn't contain definition for Begin Invoke
```

I want to know the alternate of Begin Invoke and how to implement it. Few details and example would be of great help.

Comment: Why do you want an alternative ?

Comment: @Sievajet yes because I cannot use begin Invoke with Windows Phone 8.1 development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => {});
```

is replaced by

```
private async Task MyMethod()
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { });
}
```

Comment: I dont see RunAsync in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight i see invokeasync but not run    
            await Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
          {

Comment: any suggestions i upgrade a WP 8.0 project to 8.1 and now everything runs on the worker threads, App Launching, Page navigation even stuff called with Dispatcher BeginInvoke...  HOW DO I ACCESS THE MAIN UI THREAD????